# how to make pattern for grep command on linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I hav to grep a file whos content is as follw:

bla bla bla
 
 
 this is not requred

above is my simple text file content. from which i need to get each line containing  and line next to this line.
that is in above case i need first 2 lines. how i can get them using grep command?

Comment: @balaji Please clarify your question. Do you need to strip off a part of a row that is not needed? What is a wekobj? What is " " atg? Please rewrite your question.

Comment: The question, as writte,n is very unclear about what you need.  Please be exact.

Comment: sorry.... i hav changed the question. plz tell me now.

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: you need to edit the question because the sample is not showing.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean

```
grep -A1 wekobj inputfile
```

If not, you mean

```
man grep
```

and you should go over to https://unix.stackexchange.com/